# Set The Order Query Results Display

Tags: mysql, t-sql, ddl

I need to display my `emailType` in `DESC` order.  Now it is a `varchar` field so I need it to be reverse alphabet order Z - A.  When I run my query it is displayed in `ASC` order, and since I am using a `UNION` I can't add an `ORDER BY` clause.

What change should I make to this query so I am able to set the the order the `emailType` displays in?

```
SELECT 
emailType
,aprilTotals
,mayTotals
,juneTotals
,SUM(aprilTotals+mayTotals+juneTotals) As Q2
,julyTotals
,augustTotals
,septemberTotals
,SUM(julyTotals+augustTotals+septemberTotals) As Q3
,octoberTotals
,novemberTotals
,decemberTotals
,SUM(octoberTotals+novemberTotals+decemberTotals) As Q4
,SUM(aprilTotals+mayTotals+juneTotals+julyTotals+augustTotals+septemberTotals+octoberTotals+novemberTotals+decemberTotals) As YearlyTotals
FROM TestDB.custData 
GROUP by emailType
UNION ALL
Select
'Total Emails' As Total
,SUM(aprilTotals) As April
,SUM(mayTotals) As May
,SUM(juneTotals) As June
,SUM(aprilTotals+mayTotals+juneTotals) As Q2
,SUM(julyTotals) As July
,SUM(augustTotals) As August
,SUM(septemberTotals) As September
,SUM(julyTotals+augustTotals+septemberTotals) As Q3
,SUM(octoberTotals) As October
,SUM(novemberTotals) As November
,SUM(decemberTotals) As December
,SUM(octoberTotals+novemberTotals+decemberTotals) As Q4
,SUM(aprilTotals+mayTotals+juneTotals+julyTotals+augustTotals+septemberTotals+octoberTotals+novemberTotals+decemberTotals) As YearTotals
FROM TestDB.custData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(SELECT ... )
UNION
(SELECT ... )
ORDER BY ...
```

Works just fine.  It first does the two `SELECTs`, collecting both sets of results into a temp table, dedups (if `UNION DISTINCT`), and finally does the outer `ORDER BY`.

You can optionally have `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` inside each `SELECT`.

Use parentheses (as I did) to avoid having the `ORDER BY` glom onto the second `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put () around the select union select and order the hole result

Like

```
(SELECT 
emailType
,aprilTotals
,mayTotals
,juneTotals
,SUM(aprilTotals+mayTotals+juneTotals) As Q2
,julyTotals
,augustTotals
,septemberTotals
,SUM(julyTotals+augustTotals+septemberTotals) As Q3
,octoberTotals
,novemberTotals
,decemberTotals
,SUM(octoberTotals+novemberTotals+decemberTotals) As Q4
,SUM(aprilTotals+mayTotals+juneTotals+julyTotals+augustTotals+septemberTotals+octoberTotals+novemberTotals+decemberTotals) As YearlyTotals
FROM TestDB.custData 
GROUP by emailType
UNION ALL
Select
'Total Emails' As Total
,SUM(aprilTotals) As April
,SUM(mayTotals) As May
,SUM(juneTotals) As June
,SUM(aprilTotals+mayTotals+juneTotals) As Q2
,SUM(julyTotals) As July
,SUM(augustTotals) As August
,SUM(septemberTotals) As September
,SUM(julyTotals+augustTotals+septemberTotals) As Q3
,SUM(octoberTotals) As October
,SUM(novemberTotals) As November
,SUM(decemberTotals) As December
,SUM(octoberTotals+novemberTotals+decemberTotals) As Q4
,SUM(aprilTotals+mayTotals+juneTotals+julyTotals+augustTotals+septemberTotals+octoberTotals+novemberTotals+decemberTotals) As YearTotals
FROM TestDB.custData)
ORDER BY emailType  DESC;
```

Comment: I get an error of ``incorrect syntax near UNION ALL``

Comment: can you write the hole error message please, this works as long as your querys work, you can put also () around the selects, you  query will not run in my system but i run Full_group By

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are required to review the way you save your data. From the example you posted the table is poorly structured and in any case it is not correct to make the UNION with two different data sets.

inside the SELECT you can use this to obtain a row number which you can subsequently use for your data sorts

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by emailType desc) as rownum
```